# Docker Nginx Proxy: how to route traffic to different container using path and not hostname

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy

lets say that now I have different app running on the same server on different path:

- 10.200.200.210/**app1**
- 10.200.200.210/**app2**
- 10.200.200.210/**app3**

I want to run each app on a different Docker container using nginx as a proxy.

I tried [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) and works great if I use different domain names (app1.domain.com, app2.domain.com, etc), but I'm not able to use domains, I need to use the same IP.

also I can't use different ports like:

- 10.200.200.210:81/**app1**
- 10.200.200.210:82/**app2**
- 10.200.200.210:83/**app3**

all must work on port 80.

1. Is there a way to configure **jwilder/nginx-proxy** to do this?
2. Is there another Docker image like **jwilder/nginx-proxy** that make it.
3. or pls could you give me some hint to build an nginx docker container by myself?

Comment: You can do what you want using a custom configuration in nginx.conf and build a container with it. But it will be not automated. https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Comment: I will try this : https://www.airpair.com/scalable-architecture-with-docker-consul-and-nginx  using consul-template and registrator it could be automatic.

Answer (score 36):

In case if somebody is still looking for the answer.
jwilder/nginx-proxy allows you to use custom Nginx configuration either a proxy-wide or per-VIRTUAL_HOST basis.

Here's how can you do it with Per-VIRTUAL_HOST location configuration.

1. Inside your poject folder create another folder - "vhost.d".
2. Create file "whoami.local" with custom nginx configuration inside "vhost.d" folder. **This file must have the same name as VIRTUAL_HOST!**

./vhost.d/whoami.local

```
location /app1 {
  proxy_pass http://app1:8000;
}

location /app2 {
  proxy_pass http://app2:8000;
}
```

3. Create docker-compose.yml file.

./docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    - /path/to/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:ro

  gateway:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami.local

  app1:
    image: jwilder/whoami

  app2:
    image: jwilder/whoami
```

4. Run docker-compose up
5. Check configuration

In bash run:

```
$ curl -H "Host: whoami.local" localhost:8080
I'm 1ae273bce7a4
$ curl -H "Host: whoami.local" localhost:8080/app1
I'm 52b1a7b1992a
$ curl -H "Host: whoami.local" localhost:8080/app2
I'm 4adbd3f9e7a0
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
6a659a4d4b0a        jwilder/nginx-proxy   "/app/docker-entrypo…"   54 seconds ago      Up 53 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   nginxreverseproxy_nginx-proxy_1
4adbd3f9e7a0        jwilder/whoami        "/app/http"              54 seconds ago      Up 53 seconds       8000/tcp               nginxreverseproxy_app2_1
52b1a7b1992a        jwilder/whoami        "/app/http"              54 seconds ago      Up 53 seconds       8000/tcp               nginxreverseproxy_app1_1
1ae273bce7a4        jwilder/whoami        "/app/http"              54 seconds ago      Up 53 seconds       8000/tcp               nginxreverseproxy_gateway_1
```

You can also add "whoami.local" domain to /etc/hosts file and make calls to this domain directly.

/etc/hosts

```
...
127.0.0.1   whoami.local
...
```

Result:

```
$ curl whoami.local:8080
I'm 52ed6da1e86c
$ curl whoami.local:8080/app1
I'm 4116f51020da
$ curl whoami.local:8080/app2
I'm c4db24012582
```

Comment: the solution I was looking for!

Comment: This was helpful. I got it to work without mounting vhost.d. I also did not use gateway. Instead, I added VIRTUAL_PATH environment variable to app1: and app2:. I also had to set DEFAULT_HOST environment in nginx-proxy:

Answer (score 8):

Just use [nginx](https://store.docker.com/images/nginx) image to create container,**do remember set net "host" **which will make your container share same address and port with host machine.mount `nginx.conf` file and config proxy table.for example:

docker command:

```
docker run --name http-proxy -v /host/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --net host -itd --restart always nginx
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location /app1 {
    proxy_pass YOUR_APP1_URL;
  }
  location /app2 {
    proxy_pass YOUR_APP2_URL;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a full `nginx.conf`

It redirects all to root, and only `/api` to a different container.

[Source and an example container using it](https://github.com/guysoft/ownphotos-proxy/blob/master/nginx.conf)

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
  server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend:3000/;
        }
        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://backend/api;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Default bridge network has gateway on `172.17.0.1`. You can use this IP address in your `nginx.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /app1 {
        proxy_pass  http://172.17.0.1:81;
    }
    location /app2 {
        proxy_pass  http://172.17.0.1:82;
    }
}
```

They will be accessible using port `80` from outside

You can check your bridge gateway IP address by running command `docker network inspect bridge`

Answer (score 0):

just put this inside /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
    worker_processes  1;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
      server {
            listen 80;

            location /api {
                proxy_pass http://awesome-api;
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My situation is a little bit different. I'm working on a project where Django and a couple of other apps sit behind nginx (acting as a reverse proxy)

The accepted solution did not work for me, and I think it is because the various apps do not serve files (i.e. `/app1-uri/bla/blo/bli/` and `/app1-uri/bla/blo/bli` are exactly equivalent). All static files are gathered for nginx to serve.

The 'problematic' behavior is explained [in the docs here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location). In essence, nginx picks up the uris without trailing slash and try to resolve them as resources, if it can't, it then redirects to **`/bla/blo/bli/`** ***instead of*** **`/app1-uri/bla/blo/bli/`**

This is what finally worked for me. In this example `app1-uri` is `repairapp`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    
    ...

    # This is the line that fixes the issue.
    rewrite ^/repairapp/([^static].*[^/])$ /repairapp/$1/ permanent;
    
    # This is nginx serving my static files
    location /repairapp/static/ {
        alias /var/www/repairapp/static/;
    }
    
    # This is the uri that maps to my app (no file serving here)
    location /repairapp/ {
        proxy_pass http://repairappcontainer:8000/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    
    ...
```

Note the line `rewrite ^/repairapp/([^static].*[^/])$ /repairapp/$1/ permanent;`
It rewrites and adds a trailing forward slash to any (of my app) uris that misses it; except for those that start with `/repairapp/static`. Those uris map to resources that nginx will then serve.

To debug, open a shell in the nginx container and run `curl -IL http://[server-name]/repairapp/[string-of-uris-without-trailing-slash]` to see exactly what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    environment:
      DEFAULT_HOST: nginx.proxy.default.host

  app1:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: "nginx.proxy.default.host"
      VIRTUAL_PATH: "/app1/"

  app2:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: "nginx.proxy.default.host"
      VIRTUAL_PATH: "/app2/"
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52726896/1643061