# Nginx with docker, location different from slash not found

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

#### Summary

I created this simple example to correct and check the errors that I have in another more complex project.
So I've a docker-compose file with 1 web server and 2 app and a nginx conf file.

Please note, that I'm testing it with Docker Quick Start Terminal for `Windows 10 Home Edition`, but I've tested even on `Ubuntu 18.04` and the outcome is the same.

#### Outcome

Going to: http://192.168.99.100:8080/

 Default output:

> **It works!**

The only issue here is with app2, since **I'm not able to access app2**.

Going to http://192.168.99.100:8080/app2.

Error:

> #### Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server.

I'm not understanding why I'm not able to do that, and where is the error.

#### What I've Tried

- Switch the location order, so `location /app2` after `location /`, but nothing changed
- Change the location of `location /app2` to `location /foo`, even here same outcome.
- Change the path related to the previous example, anything different from `location /` does not works. (e.g. `location /bar` `location /foobar` `location /test`)
- Change `location /` in order to refer the app2 instead of app1, and it works but in this way I can't reach app1.

  ```
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://app2:80;
  }
  ```

  location /app1 {
      proxy_pass http://app1:80;
  }

#### Code

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    networks:
        - app1_net
        - app2_net

  app1:
      image: httpd:latest
      networks:
        - app1_net

  app2:
      image: httpd:latest
      networks:
        - app2_net

networks:
  app1_net:
  app2_net:
```

`nginx.conf`

```
events {}
http {
    server{
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name localhost;

        location /app2 {
            proxy_pass http://app2:80;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app1:80;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way, use a regex to allow sub folders navigation and a perfect match on /app2 to redirect traffic on http://app2:

```
location ~ ^/app2/(.*)$ {
  proxy_pass http://app2/$1;
}
location = /app2 {
  proxy_pass http://app2/;
}
location / {
  proxy_pass http://app1;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying it, I will let you know

Comment: It works! I missed the final slash after `http://app2`! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have added [another stackoverflow answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69794097/9034699)

It is summarized here:

- My setup has a couple of apps sitting behind nginx. I want to redirect `/appx-uri/bla/blo/bli` to `/appx-uri/bla/blo/bli/` ***instead of*** `/bla/blo/bli/` which is the [default nginx behavior](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).
- Also, all my static files (for an app) are gathered for nginx to serve `/repairapp/static/`.

Adding the directive `rewrite ^/repairapp/([^static].*[^/])$ /repairapp/$1/ permanent;` in the server block fixes it.

I then have

- To fix the issue: `rewrite ^/repairapp/([^static].*[^/])$ /repairapp/$1/ permanent;`
- To have nginx serve resources `location /repairapp/static/ {`
- To access an app `location /repairapp/ {`