# how to deal with changing ips of docker compose containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've setup an app where a nodejs backend has to communicate with a rasa chatbot backend through a react frontend. All services are running through the same docker-compose. Being a docker beginner there are some things I'm not sure about:

communication between host and container is done using the container's ip

- browser opening the local react server running on `localhost:3000` or `172.22.0.1:3000`
- browser sending a request to the express backend on `localhost:4000` `172.22.0.2:4000`

however communication between two docker containers is done is the container's name:

- rasa server conmmunicating with the rasa custom action server through `http://action_server:5055/webhooks`
- rasa custom action server communicating with the express backend through `http://backend_name:4000/users/`

my problem is that when I need to contact the rasa backend from my react front end I need to put the rasa docker container's ip which (sometimes) changes upon docker-compose reinitialization. To workaround this I do a `docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' app_rasa_1` to get the ip and manually change it into the react frontend.

is there a way to avoid changing the ip alltogether and using the container name (or an alias/link) or what would be a way to automate the change of the container's ip in the react frontend (are environment variables updated via a script an option?)

Comment: You say that all services are running in the same compose, does that exclude the front end app? If yes, expose a port for the service you need to talk to and point to `localhost:<exposed_port>`. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports. The nginx container has an example of how it works https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx

Answer (score 2):

Completely ignore the container-private IP addresses.  They're implementation details that have several practical problems, including (as you note) them changing when a container is recreated.  (They're also unreachable on non-Linux hosts, or if the browser isn't on the same host as the containers.)

You show the correct patterns in your question.  For calls between containers, use the container names as host names (this setup is described more in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).  For calls from outside containers, including from browser-based applications, use the host's DNS name or IP address and the first number from the `ports:` you publish.

If the browser application needs to contact a back-end server, it needs a path to do this.  This could be via published `ports:`, or one of your other components could proxy the request to the service (maybe using the [`express-http-proxy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy) middleware).

A dedicated container that only proxies to other backend services is also a useful pattern ([Docker Nginx Proxy: how to route traffic to different container using path and not hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514293/docker-nginx-proxy-how-to-route-traffic-to-different-container-using-path-and-n) includes some examples), particularly since this will let you use path-only URLs like `/api` or `/rasa` in your browser application.  If the React application is served from `http://localhost:8080/`, and the main backend is `http://localhost:8080/api`, then you can just make HTTP requests to `/api` and they will be interpreted relative to the page's URL.  This avoids the hostname problem completely, so long as your reverse proxy has path-based routes to every container you need to directly contact.