# UI cannot access Node server when launched on Docker and served over an IP

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-network

This is my situation.
Docker Containers

```
1. Node/Play/Any BackEnd Server
2. React
3. Other services
```

I have launched them using docker-compose and everything works fine. The problem is:
When I launch docker-compose on a VM and serve the UI over an IP it is not able to access the node server.

It happens since the React Code is configured to access the Node server at `http://node-backend:9000`(where `node-backend` is the name of the docker container that runs nodejs) and react sends this exact URL to the client on some other machine, which cannot resolve this address since `http://node-backend:9000` is internal to Docker.

How do I solve this issue without using nginx or any other proxying service?

Comment: My recommendation would in fact be to add an Nginx reverse proxy to this stack; see for example [Docker Nginx Proxy: how to route traffic to different container using path and not hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514293/docker-nginx-proxy-how-to-route-traffic-to-different-container-using-path-and-n) for some inspiration.  Once you do that, you can configure the backend URL in the React application to a path-only relative URL like `/api` and it won't care what host/port it's deployed on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your configuration of React. Never use the local container name when you want to server over the network.

Here are the steps you need to take

1. Port mapping for node server. You are probably doing this already.
2. Make sure that the port 9000 on server is exposed.
3. Configure the react app to use the IP address to connect to node server (NOT named instance).
4. At this point, you should see the calls happening over network like http://:9000

Comment: How do I do step 3? Right now the Public IP changes whenever the VM is relaunched. I don't want to configure that IP address anywhere, only the end user  should know that address

Comment: If the ip address changes every time, here are two ways to solve. Depending on your case, you could go with either approach. 
1. You can use the dns name or the machine name (this should not change every time) instead of its IP address. 
2. If React app and Node server lies on the same server, you could configure React app to use the ‘host’ IP address of React app and build the url with node server port number.

Comment: 2 sounds great, how do I do that?

Comment: Use window.location.host to get the the ipaddress of host. Build the node url based on that. 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp