# Request from the application inside the client container to the server container is not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, react-fullstack

I have a React application and a server with a database. In the application, I make a request like fetch('http://serverstrapi:1337/api/auth/local/register/') or fetch('http://serverstrapi/api/auth/local/register/') and I see:

[image]

However, if I access the client container by exec and perform a ping 'serverstrapi', it is successful. Additionally, if I change 'serverstrapi' to 'localhost:3001', everything works fine, the external address works.

Here is the docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - SERVER_PORT=1337
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
    ports:
      - 8081:3000

  serverstrapi:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./server/config:/server/config
      - ./server/src:/server/src
      - ./server/package.json:/server/package.json
      - ./server/yarn.lock:/server/yarn.lock
      - ./server/.env:/server/.env
      - ./server/public/uploads:/server/public/uploads
    ports:
      - 3001:1337
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 4001:5432
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5001:8080

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - client
      - serverstrapi
```

I have tried removing Nginx completely from the docker-compose file and deleting all networks and containers to start fresh. I have also tried various variations of the 'serverstrapi' address, such as with a port and without a port, etc.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: what is in the client ? a static website ?
are you trying to access that website with the browser and your browser i showing that error ?

Comment: In the client container, there is a React application. From this application, I am trying to communicate with a server running in another container using the container name defined in the docker-compose file. I want to access them using the internal Docker addresses. Both of these containers are using the 'node:18-alpine' image.

Comment: i shared my answer. you can not use serverstrapi as hostname in the browser because browser is not a part of the server container network and cant resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're encountering an issue due to the way Docker networking and web browsers interact.

When you access the static page served by the client container from your browser, your browser retrieves the static files and then tries to execute the API calls. The problem arises because your browser is not part of the Docker network where the server container is running. Therefore, it cannot resolve the container name (or hostname) to an IP address.

In Docker, container names are resolvable to their respective IP addresses within the same Docker network. However, this name resolution is not accessible outside of the Docker network environment, which is why your browser can't resolve the hostname or container name to an IP.

In order to access your server container's API, you'll need to use either the IP address of the machine where Docker is running (assuming you've exposed the necessary ports) or a domain name that has been appropriately configured to point to that IP.

Remember, your client-side code (like JavaScript running in a browser) executes outside of the Docker environment, so it doesn't have access to the Docker internal DNS. Any API endpoints it needs to access must be reachable within the context of the network it's running on, typically the public internet if it's a web application.

Solution would be to pass the server api hostname/ip and port as environment variable to your react app container and you modify the url of the server api to the environment variables passed.

Comment: I have come across similar information before, but I assumed that something was clearly wrong because when I connect to the database using Adminer in the browser, I simply specify the service name from the docker-compose file, which in my case is 'db,' and it works fine. This has confused me.

Considering the amount of time I've been struggling with this, you are probably right. Thank you.

Comment: @ДенисБеспалов Your welcome. Don't forget to make the server url/port as environment variable for the client/website docker container.

Comment: there is one more solution. you could modify the configuration of the nginx and forward specific path to the server api and that will work also.

for example: 
you could configure nginx of your client container is such a way
/ -> react app
/api -> serverstrapi

you can access the api with ip-of-the-client-container/api

Comment: Here is the solution with nginx: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514293/docker-nginx-proxy-how-to-route-traffic-to-different-container-using-path-and-n

Comment: your welcome. dont forget to configure nginx to forward the request url and dont forget to change the base url of your server api to .../api/...
if you want to go with the nginx solution.

Comment: This solution will work because the nginx in the client container will take your request and make a request on its behalf. it can make connection with your server api because it is in the client container and can connect to the server api